# how can i rearrange a table display so every th will be above it's specific td's?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 1 description text and 5 td's (links).

See [`jsfiddle here`](https://jsfiddle.net/ny2djt4x/2/)

I'm trying to change the display of the table for mobile devices.
So The th (description text) will be centered in 1 line.
and below it, in a different line, the 5 td's will take 100% width.

here is my desire display of the table:
[image: desire display]

At first, i tried to use flexbox for this. using the tr as a container, and then i tried to put the th (description text) in 1 div and the 5 tds in a second div. but that unfortunately this did not work because it seems that div canno't be a direct child of a tr.

for some reasons i have to stay with the table structure.

Any ideas how can i get my specific display target?
Thanks

Comment: Check the updated solution.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: @codingnighter2000 If the solution solved your query, it'd be appreciated to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since you need the **categoryText** to be in a *different row on its own*, just make a **seperate row** for it with the `colspan="5"` (it takes up 5 column spaces), since each row will take 5 column widths.
- Then, you can use `text-align:center` to **align the contents in the center** of their respective cells.

> You cannot make use of div **outside the tr or directly inside the tr** to apply it as flex to change the layout as it is. You can **wrap div in your th or td** but that won't do you anything good either for what you want to achieve, if you want the table to be responsive as in "make the rows wrap" you shouldn't use html tables at all, but rather use **flexbox** or **grid** to achieve it.

```css
#table1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

tbody tr.rowTr > td {
padding-bottom:1em;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="rowTr">
      <th class="category" colspan="5">categoryText</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowTr">
      <td class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd11"> <a href="#"> td 1 </a>
      </td>
      <td class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd12"> <a href="#"> td 2 </a>
      </td>
      <td class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd13"> <a href="#"> td 3 </a>
      </td>
      <td class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd14"> <a href="#"> td 4 </a>
      </td>
      <td class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd15"> <a href="#"> td 5 </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowTr">
      <th class="category" colspan="5">categoryText</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowTr">
      <td class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd11"> <a href="#"> td 1 </a>
      </td>
      <td class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd12"> <a href="#"> td 2 </a>
      </td>
      <td class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd13"> <a href="#"> td 3 </a>
      </td>
      <td class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd14"> <a href="#"> td 4 </a>
      </td>
      <td class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd15"> <a href="#"> td 5 </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Here's an additional code structure entirely using flexbox to achieve the desired effect:**

> The below is just a demonstration, you can use the media queries and tweak it around for your requirements.

```css
#table1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.tbody .tr > span:nth-child(n+1) {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.tbody {
  width: 100%;
}

.tbody .tr {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.tbody .row {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .tbody .tr .category {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="table1">
  <div class="tbody">
    <div class="tr">
      <span class="category">categoryText</span>
      <span class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd11"> <a href="#"> td 1 </a>
      </span>
      <span class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd12"> <a href="#"> td 2 </a>
      </span>
      <span class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd13"> <a href="#"> td 3 </a>
      </span>
      <span class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd14"> <a href="#"> td 4 </a>
      </span>
      <span class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd15"> <a href="#"> td 5 </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <span class="category">categoryText</span>
      <span class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd11"> <a href="#"> td 1 </a>
      </span>
      <span class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd12"> <a href="#"> td 2 </a>
      </span>
      <span class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd13"> <a href="#"> td 3 </a>
      </span>
      <span class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd14"> <a href="#"> td 4 </a>
      </span>
      <span class="tabkeTd" id="tabkeTd15"> <a href="#"> td 5 </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```